Why doesn't rust compiler consider argument reference in borrow checking?
I am curious about the error output of the compiler for the following function which is an example from The Rust Brown Book (no edited).
fn remove_zeros(v: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for (i, t) in v.iter().enumerate().rev() {
        if *t == 0 {
            v.remove(i);
            v.shrink_to_fit();
        }
    }
}

At first I thought the argument v:&mut vec<i32> is a mutable reference, so it cannot co-exist with v.iter().enumerate().rev(). But then I found the error doesn't say anything with the argument input but only raises an error with the first real mutable use of the v.

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> test.rs:5:13
  |
3 |     for (i, t) in v.iter().enumerate().rev() {
  |                   --------------------------
  |                   |
  |                   immutable borrow occurs here
  |                   immutable borrow later used here
4 |         if *t == 0 {
5 |             v.remove(i);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

Shouldn't it make more sense if the compiler checks the argument type's compatibility with the usage inside ?
At first I didn't care too much about this, and then I found The Brown Rust Book keeps asking questions about what is the error "invalid immutable borrow first" OR "invalid mutable borrow first".

I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you think v.iter() (an immutable call) shouldn't be allowed when v is a mutable reference?

Note that your function can be written more efficiently as v.retain (|t| *t != 0); v.shrink_to_fit();

I think that because the type usage inside the loop may be correct. Add a break just afther shrink_to_fit() and it will compile ok. The error actually happens because there is a next loop run.

Regarding your question, it is perfectly all right to make immutable calls on a &mut ref. There is an issue only when you start interleaving mutable an immutable calls (e.g. calling v.remove while the v.iter is still live).

@Jmb but isn't there a rule asking "You can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references to a value at any given time." and in this case, the immutable reference is weaved into the live scope of a mutable reference.

@kmdreko yes, when the argument was mutable, should the v.iter be stopped in the first place?

@Jmb so the pure declaration of a mutable doesn't count in this rule ?

A mutable reference can be easily reborrowed as an immutable reference or even another mutable reference (often with a shorter lifetime):
let v_ref: & _ = &*v;
let v_mut: &mut _ = &mut *v;

This is done implicitly by the compiler all the time when calling methods and passing parameters - like in your case v.iter() creates an immutable reference to v (to pass as the self) by reborrowing. It should also make sense intuitively: if you're allowed to mutate a value, why wouldn't you also be allowed to not mutate it?
Doesn't this violate the "mutable references are exclusive" rule?
No. Reborrowing will effectively "lock out" the original mutable reference while the reborrowed reference is still alive. That is what the compiler is complaining about here: you created a reference via v.iter() that is held until the for-loop ends which "locks out" v from being used, but you're using v within that loop which creates the conflict.
